# JMeter. How do I transfer a unique id from one query to another?

Tags: jmeter

ApiSaveRegistration generates an id to pass to the next query, but the id is always unique, how do I make the id be passed to the next query?

[1. ApiSaveRegistration](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BUp26.png)

[2. highlighted the area where the id from ApiSaveRegistration should be inserted](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gldhJ.png)

I can probably do it with variables. Can you please help me?

Answer (score 0):

You have to extract the Registration id into a variable by using Post processor(JSON Extractor/Regular expression Extractor) .Add it to the request in which Registration id is getting generated and pass it to subsequent requests where ever required.

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor

https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#Regular_Expression_Extractor

Comment: Thank you! Can you also tell me how I can replace only part of the query?
I only need this number(BillNumber): {"Success":true,"Redirect":"/acquiring/Free/Payment?BillNumber=20221215000040"}
Insert in this request: GET https://rr-dev.ru/acquiring/Free/Payment?BillNumber= (here, but this number is always unique too, it is created in the previous request)

Comment: Suppose If you captured the dynamic value in variable named Var1  ,it can be replaced by ${Var1}

Comment: I need from this query: {"Success":true, "Redirect":"/acquiring/Free/Payment?BillNumber=20221215000058"} to transfer only: 20221215000058 into the following query

The next request is: GET https://rr-dev.ru/acquiring/Free/Payment?BillNumber=

I use this tool:  https://ibb.co/5cWn9DH

Answer (score 0):

You can add a [JSON Extractor](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/component_reference.html#JSON_Extractor) as a child of the request which returns this RegistrationId and configure it like:

[image]

then you will be able to refer the extracted value as `${id}` [JMeter Variable](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html) where required.

More information:

- [JsonPath - Getting Started](https://github.com/json-path/JsonPath#getting-started)
- [How to Use the JSON Extractor For Testing](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/json-extractor)